# How to check if both query excecuted successfully?

Tags: php, mysql, nested, logic

I want to INSTERT into 2 different tables. People will complete a form, where they enter their user data, and their company data. I tested this form, and when everything correct it's fine but...when the user data is ok, and the company data has errors, the user insert runs and I don't want it. Vica versa..
My code right now: (just a markup)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (name, email, password) VALUES (:username, :email, :password)";
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql) {
    ... //bind parameters
    if($stmt->execute()){
      echo "Successfully registered user";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO company (title, number, address) VALUES (:title, :number, :address)";
      $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql) {
        ... //bind parameters
        if($stmt->execute()){
        echo "Successfully registered company";
      }
    }
  }
}
unset($stmt);
```

I want to check both, and when there is no error, then run both query.
How do I nest it?

Comment: Validate your data then? `// bind parameters` you so deeply thought necessary to comment out is the part you should validate before passing it to the query.

Comment: Use transactions

Answer (score 1):

You can use transactions `beginTransaction`, `rollBack`, `commit` with try and catch.

```
$dbh->beginTransaction()
try {
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (name, email, password) VALUES (:username, :email, :password)";
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql) {
    ... //bind parameters
    if($stmt->execute()){
      echo "Successfully registered user";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO company (title, number, address) VALUES (:title, :number, :address)";
      $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql) {
        ... //bind parameters
        if($stmt->execute()){
        echo "Successfully registered company";
      }
    }
  }
}
} catch(\Exception $e) 
    $dbh->rollBack();
}
$dbh->commit();
unset($stmt);
```

Comment: I think the success message should be moved after transaction commit.

Answer (score -1):

```
    try {
        $pdo->prepare($agr_query_string);
        $commited = $pdo->commit();
        if($commited){
         echo "Success";
        }else{
         echo "Fail";
         $pdo->rollBack();
        }
      } catch (PDOException $e) {

        $pdo->rollBack();
        print "rollBack : fail";

        //throw new $e;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. No-one learns anything from that. If you think your code solves the problem, then add a description which explains what you changed, and _why_.

Comment: Well I was hoping you'd actually edit the answer to improve it, rather than just acknowledge the comment!